# Debugging cordova app for Windows Phone

Tags: css, visual-studio, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have `cordova 5.3.3` and my app is already working very well for Android. Now I'm trying to build it for `Windows Phone 8` and `Windows Phone 8.1`.
The problem is that I found out that some `.css` files are not loaded (I'm running the app with both emulator and device with Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1 x64).

How can I debug the app to find what files are not loaded during app running?

I tried to use `ripple-emulator` (https://github.com/apache/incubator-ripple) but I think it does not work with Internet Explorer on Windows or maybe I can't make it work (I already use it on Linux with Chromium and the Android platform and it works).

I also tried to use `Visual Studio 2013`: I have opened the `.sln` file in `/platforms/wp8` and ran the app, so I have whatched the output console, but I think that it does not help me because I could not find the informations I need about the `.css` files that are not loaded.

Any help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you run the app in the vs debugger the f12 tools will attach and you can view the Dom from visual studio. Just press f5 in vs to build, deploy and run with the debugger attached.

Comment: ok thanks, I just can see the console output, but not the DOM.

Comment: It could be that the DOM explorer doesn't open automatically in VS 2013 (it does in 2015). You can open it manually. Go to Debug -> Windows -> DOM Explorer to force it to open.

Comment: I tried that, but the option is disabled. I think that it could be because of the project type. It's a cordova project taken from `/platforms/wp8/`. What do you think?

Comment: Same problem here. The DOM Explorer on VS 2013 Express with a cordova project was disabled. Did you fixed?

Comment: Not in vs 2013, no. Please upgrade to vs 2015.